How to make data slicer dynamic
I want to add a slicer for the closed_date field in my report.
I’ve encountered a few difficulties:

The far-right date should be the latest possible date in the closed_date field. I need it to always show today’s date. I tried artificially adding today’s date and then filtering out that record from the report so it wouldn’t skew the statistics. However, this option complicates the query significantly.

When I upload the report to the server, I need the left date to be 01.06.2024 and the right date to be today’s date. But the report uploads in the same format as it was locally, and it doesn’t change on the server. I tried adding a button to clear all slicers, but then the left date will be 17.01.2024 instead of 01.06.2024.



